# Algorithmic complexity of MongoDB's $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, time-complexity

What is time and memory complexity of this aggregation?

```
.aggregate([{
   $group: {
       _id: {year: '$YEAR', month: '$MONTH', user: '$USER_ID'},
       foo: {$sum: '$SOME_FIELD'}
    }
}])
```

MongoDB documentation doesn't provide such information.